# Azure Data Factory Web Activity - exclamation mark "!" in URL issue

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-factory

I am using Web Activity with GET method to extract data from REST endpoint. The URL contains exclamation mark character

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBRpW.png

However in debug output I get the following URL as input to the web activity:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f50J8.png

Somehow the space is added before exclamation mark. I tried using replace function, concatenation, URL encoding, but it still adds this space to the URL.

I tried to google it but found no such example.

Comment: Please provided the URL links as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing any space before the exclamation (!) mark in the link when tried.

[image]

Try to open the JSON code of web activity in the pipeline and check if you see any spaces and remove them.

You can also use replace function to replace the space from the link with empty.

```
@replace('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/45078642-72ff-4519-bcce-21440e17a9bc/drives/b!QoYHRf9yGUW8ziFEDhepvOZxCMwcjRpKued1n_tDwksC4SLkzZJUTb_ymC6FSdiQ/root/children', ' ','')
```